# Disabling HTML PDF Viewer Object

Tags: html, css, angularjs, pdf

I have embedded a PDF viwer in my page and would like to disable the object in such a way that it's not possible to interact with it (no scrolling, no zoom in/out). My html object looks like this:

```
<div id="pdf">
        <object width="650" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="./forms/my.pdf?#zoom=45&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" id="pdf_content">
            <p>PDF could not be loaded.</p>
        </object>
    </div>
```

Is it even possible to disable the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PDF is rendering as intended on page load and you simply want to prevent mouse interaction, you can cover it up with an invisible element like so with CSS:

```
#pdf {
  position: relative;
}

#pdf::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

And per your request, a way to toggle this on/off (using jQuery):

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function() {

  if ($('#pdf').hasClass('enable')) {

    $('#pdf').removeClass('enable').on('mousedown scroll', function() { return false; });
    $(this).text('Enable PDF Interaction');

  } else {

    $('#pdf').addClass('enable').off();
    $(this).text('Disable PDF Interaction');

  }
});
```

```css
#pdf {
  position: relative;
  /* sizes for example since PDF won't load: */
  width: 650px;
  height: 500px;
}
#pdf::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#pdf.enable::before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">Disable PDF Interaction</button>

<div id="pdf" class="enable">
  <object width="650" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/dc/Convergent_Synthesis_Example.pdf" id="pdf_content">
    <p>PDF could not be loaded.</p>
  </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx, it is partly working. I still can scroll up and down however and I would like to grey out the area, so that it's visually clear to the user as well.

Comment: @YourReflection Not sure what we can do about the scrolling - usually an element like that will catch the scroll wheel. I appended a line to add a background (black, 30% transparency) - see if that gives the effect you'd like. You can adjust it to white instead for a brighter overlay (`255, 255, 255`) and tweak the alpha value (`.3`).

Comment: Thank you! Only thing remaining is the scrolling now :)

Comment: Another thing: how can I enable it again once some button is clicked for instance?

Comment: @YourReflection I've appended my answer with a functional example of how to use jQuery to make a button enable/disable those styles. Additionally, I added a `mousedown` and `scroll` event listener when the element is disabled so clicks and scrolling are intercepted if they're within the `#pdf` container. That still might not work since `object` elements are handled by plugins, but worth a shot.

Comment: Thanx alot, Will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with AngularJS?

Comment: I got it, thanx :)